# How to scroll to a certain item in a Column(Modifier.verticalScroll())?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a Column with TextViews with indices from -10 to 10.

```
 Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .verticalScroll(
                state = scrollState,
                enabled = isScrollEnabled,
                reverseScrolling = reverseScrollDirection
            )) {
    for(i in -10..10) {
        TextView("Index $i")
    }
}
```

Naturally, this Column start with -10 and is incrementing by 1 until 10; so I have to scroll forward all the 21 indices (picture left hand side).

[image]

How can I align 0 to the beginning, so that I start the view scrollable either 10 back until -10 or 10 forward until 10 (see attached picture right hand side)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack compose code to scroll down to the position of a specific UI element on clicking a Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67586828/jetpack-compose-code-to-scroll-down-to-the-position-of-a-specific-ui-element-on)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly retrieve that specific item's position using a `Modifier.onGloballyPositioned`, then scroll to that item using `LaunchedEffect`.

```
@Composable
fun SmartScrollableColumn() {

    var itemPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0F) }
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        scrollState.animateScrollTo(itemPosition.toInt())
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
    ) {
        for (i in -10..10) {
            Text(
                text = "Index $i",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .then(
                        // Only store the position of this item (in this case item zero):
                        if (i == 0) Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates ->
                            itemPosition = layoutCoordinates.positionInRoot().y
                        } else Modifier
                    )
                    .padding(all = 5.dp)
            )
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Column doesn't have a concept of **item**, it has just a bunch of composable functions called inside of it. Because of that, `ScrollState` only has a method to scroll to position **in pixels**.

If you know the height of your items, you can calculate the pixel position and pass it to `rememberScrollState()`. Otherwise, you can use `LazyColumn` which can scroll to specific item.

Answer (score 0):

you can scroll to the last item like this:

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
Button(onClick = {
coroutineScope.launch { 
scrollState.scrollBy((scrollState.maxValue - scrollState.value).toFloat())
}
 }) {
        Text(text = "Scroll To Last Item")
    }
```